# NSDateFormatter and different result of 'MMM'

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, xcode7

I have a curious anomaly with NSDateFormatter. Consider this Swift playground code:

```
import Foundation

let locale  = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"sv_SE_POSIX")
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d MMM H:mm"
formatter.locale = locale
let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: NSTimeInterval(1391434807))
let d = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

I get different values for `d` on two different machines. Both machines use OS X 10.10.5 and Xcode 7.0.1. Because of this difference I also get a failing unit test on the build slave.

Local machine: `d == "3 feb 14:40"`

Build slave:   `d == "3 feb. 14:40"`

What is causing the period `.` suffix  on the build slave?

Comment: Do both machines have the same locale settings etc (System Preferences > Language & Region)?

Comment: Yes, same settings. I don't see how it would affect this code snippet though, since I explicitly set the locale.

Comment: You'd be surprised...

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you remove the `_POSIX`?

Comment: No difference if I remove the _POSIX. I do see now though that the '.' is not there on Xcode 6.4.

Comment: Just in case, please check the value of the formatterBehavior property (on your formatters)?

Comment: formatter.formatterBehavior.rawValue == 1040 on both machines.

Comment: Ok, let's continue guessing and checking: what about the dateStyle on your formatters? The idea behind my suggestions is the same as @Droppy's one: it's all about MacOS settings on your machines.

Comment: You are importing UIKit and the question is tagged [ios], therefore I assume  that the code runs on an iOS device or the iOS Simulator? – In that case the regional settings of the *device* are relevant, not the settings on your Mac.

Comment: The UIKit import was a leftover from old playground code, edited now. The project with unit tests is iOS yes, but the same problem is there in above Playground snippet.

Comment: Why are you using `sv_SE_POSIX` instead of `en_US_POSIX`? Do both machines have this desired locale installed? Use print(NSLocale.availableLocaleIdentifiers()) to check. In my setup the output is with the `.` and I don't have the `sv_SE_POSIX` on the output of the method I mentioned.

Comment: @Otávio: because I want to use Swedish locale.

Comment: @pojo Ok, I undestand that. But then the question turns to be: Do both systems have the desired locale?